# Synchronizing AVSpeechSynthesizer with another animation in my scene

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to synchronize the completion of  multiple actions within a scene (e.g. speech, video and animations) and trigger another action after multiple actions in a set are complete. The simple case below prints something after both speech and SKAction are complete.

```
    import SpriteKit
    import PlaygroundSupport
    import AVFoundation

    let start = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50)
    let end = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 50)
    let radius: CGFloat = 20;
    let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200)
    let skview = SKView(frame: bounds)
    PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = skview
    PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

    class MyScene: SKScene,AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
        var motionComplete = false
        var speechComplete = false
        let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer();
        override func sceneDidLoad() {
            synth.delegate = self

            synth.speak(AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Ola"))

            let greenball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: radius);
            greenball.position = start;
            greenball.fillColor = .green;

            let motionpath = CGMutablePath();
            motionpath.move(to: start)
            motionpath.addLine(to: end);
            let motion = SKAction.follow(motionpath, asOffset: false, orientToPath: true,duration: 2);
            greenball.run(motion) {
                print ("motion complete")
                self.motionComplete = true;
                self.syncUp()
            };
            self.addChild(greenball);
       }

        func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
            print ("speech complete")
            speechComplete = true;
            self.syncUp()
        }

        func syncUp() {
            if (motionComplete && speechComplete) {
                print ("speech and motion complete");
            }
        }

    }



    let scene = MyScene(size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 200));

    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
    scene.size = skview.bounds.size

    skview.presentScene(scene);
```

In reality I am trying to coordinate  multiple user-driven and app-driven actions. Are there better techniques to achieve bug-free synchronization?